# jQuery click enter in select bootstrap searchable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

I need when I click enter in input for select searchable select, not working and alert not working for this.

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2">Tags</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <select class="form-control m-bootstrap-select" id="add_tag" data-live-search="true" name="tags">
                        <option value="1">tag</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How to make it?
I use this code, but not working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#add_tag').keypress(function (e) {
            var key = e.which;
            if(key == 13)
            {
                alert(123);
            }
        });
 });
```

Comment: this is works on codepen? https://codepen.io/dgknca/pen/dwxweO?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Bind your select element to keydown:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add_tag').bind('keydown', function(event) {
        switch(event.keyCode){
           case 13:
               alert(123);
               break;
           default:
               break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is worked!!
$(document).ready(function () {
            var tag = $('div.bs-searchbox').find('input[type=text]');
            $(tag).bind('keydown', function(event) {
                switch(event.keyCode){
                    case 13:
                        alert(123);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });
        });

Comment: there is not even an input[type='text'] or .bs-searchbox in your original question, but glad you figured it out..